# How to launch a .service file Using Systemd -Dbus interface?

Tags: linux, systemd, services, d-bus

I need to call a service file using Systemd -D bus Interface.
I  think using the `g_dbus_connection_call_sync()`  method we can communicate on D-Bus
I need `g_dbus_connection_call_sync()` to call method `StartUnit()`;
Also, I Need to specify StartUnit() parameter mode as "`replace`".

============================================================

```
#define SYSTEMD_MNGR_IF  "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
#define SYSTEMD_UNIT_IF  "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit"
#define SYSTEMD_SERVICE_IF  "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Service"
#define SYSTEMD_PROP_IF  "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
#define SYSTEMD_SERVICE "org.freedesktop.systemd1"
#define SYSTEMD_OBJ "/org/freedesktop/systemd1"

GDBusConnection*   systemd_conn = NULL ;


    ret = g_dbus_connection_call_sync(systemd_conn,
            SYSTEMD_SERVICE,
            SYSTEMD_OBJ,
            SYSTEMD_MNGR_IF,
            "StartUnit",
            NULL,
            NULL,
            G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
            -1,
            NULL,
            &error);
```

====================================================================
Where pass replace parameter?
do I need to define a new method StartUnit?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a raw d-bus solution like you wanted, but this uses `systemd`'s own wrapper around dbus, tweaked for a systemd interface.

I use [`sd_bus_call_method()`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_bus_call_method.html#) using using `libsystemd-dev`:

- `sd_bus* bus` is an object allocated with with [`sd_bus_default()`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_bus_default.html#).
- `name` is an unescaped unit name (i.e. `foo.service`)
- `method` is one of `"StartUnit"`, `"StopUnit"`, `"RestartUnit"`

```
#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>

static void CallMethodSS(
    sd_bus* bus,
    const std::string& name,
    const std::string& method)
{
    sd_bus_error err = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;
    sd_bus_message* msg = nullptr;
    int r;

    r = sd_bus_call_method(bus,
        "org.freedesktop.systemd1",         /* <service>   */
        "/org/freedesktop/systemd1",        /* <path>      */
        "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager", /* <interface> */
        method.c_str(),                     /* <method>    */
        &err,                               /* object to return error in */
        &msg,                               /* return message on success */
        "ss",                               /* <input_signature (string-string)> */
        name.c_str(),  "replace" );         /* <arguments...> */

    if (r < 0)
    {
        std::string err_str("Could not send " + method +
                            " command to systemd for service: " + name +
                            ". Error: " + err.message );

        sd_bus_error_free(&err);
        sd_bus_message_unref(msg);
        throw exception(err_str);
    }

    // Extra stuff that might be useful:  display the response...
    char* response;
    r = sd_bus_message_read(msg, "o", &response);
    if (r < 0)
    {
      LogError("Failed to parse response message: %s\n", strerror(-r) );
    }

    sd_bus_error_free(&err);
    sd_bus_message_unref(msg);
}
```

Good explanation from the systemd dev's here:

http://0pointer.de/blog/the-new-sd-bus-api-of-systemd.html

Answer (score 0):

My other answer uses another library.  This answer is a guess based on my experience with `sd_bus` and reading the GDBusConnection documentation.

The signature of [`g_dbus_connection_call_sync`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/gio/GDBusConnection.html#g-dbus-connection-call-sync) is:

```
GVariant *  g_dbus_connection_call_sync(
    GDBusConnection    *connection,
    const gchar        *bus_name,
    const gchar        *object_path,
    const gchar        *interface_name,
    const gchar        *method_name,
    GVariant           *parameters,
    const GVariantType *reply_type,
    GDBusCallFlags      flags,
    gint                timeout_msec,
    GCancellable       *cancellable,
    GError            **error
);
```

`GVariant* parameters` is the most interesting part here.  `Systemd`'s [`"StartUnit"`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/)  method takes two parameters:

```
      StartUnit(in  s name,  /* Name of the unit (foo.service) */
                in  s mode,  /* Mode of operation (replace) */
                out o job);
```

Therefore we need to populate `GVariant* parameters` with these two strings.  We can do that with:

```
g_variant_new ("(ss)", "foo.service", "replace"),
```

The `"(ss)"` is the format string, which tells `g_variant_new` to create a variant containing two strings.  The next two parameters are those strings.

If I am to apply that to your code, I would get this:

```
    ret = g_dbus_connection_call_sync(
            systemd_conn,
            SYSTEMD_SERVICE,
            SYSTEMD_OBJ,
            SYSTEMD_MNGR_IF,
            "StartUnit",
            g_variant_new ("(ss)", "foo.service", "replace"),
            NULL,
            G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
            -1,
            NULL,
            &error );
```